# In what situation would the Vin pin be attached to any of the I/O pins?

Tags: serial

In what situation would the Vin pin be attached to any of the I/O pins?

Also, in what situation would the Vin pin be attached to an external circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Vin is exactly the same as using the barrel jack (DC in) on the Arduino.  You can use it when you want to power your Arduino from an external source and you don't want to have the bulk of a big power plug.  It can also be used as a power output when you are using the barrel jack, for instance for powering relays or motors.  It just saves on having to splice wires into the cable of a wall wart, for example.

The voltage you feed in to the Vin pin should be of the same specification as the barrel jack - that is, between 7 and 12V.  From there, just like the barrel jack, it goes to the 5V regulator to provide the 5V for the board, and then on to the 3.3V regulator for low powered peripherals.

If, at any time, you power the board from the USB and have something connected to the Vin pin that consumes power you risk damaging the 5V regulator on the Arduino since power will flow backwards through it form 5V to Vin, which it really isn't meant to do.  In these situations it is good to connect a diode between 5V and Vin such that the anode is on 5V and the cathode on Vin - so that if the 5V is higher than the Vin voltage then the current will bypass the regulator safely.

Comment: Thanks, also when do you think it would be acceptable to attach the positive or negative end of a power supply to an I/O pin?

Comment: @abc12333333 You have asked that as a separate question - see my answer there.

Comment: @Majenko `Vin is exactly the same as using the barrel jack`. The barrel jack has a polarity protection diode, while Vin hasn't (at least on the UNO). Other than that, they are indeed the same.

Answer (score 2):

Vin connected to an IO pin: If you want to damage your Arduino.

Hypothetically, I could imagine a misguided attempt to detect if it's being powered from a barrel jack or from USB, but the higher voltage (and it will ALWAYS be a higher voltage if powered from that rail) is likely to damage the chip

To do that safely/correctly, you would need a voltage divider, to reduce both the voltage to a level below the +5v level.

Vin to an external circuit is very reasonable. If you have, for example, a motor that needs +12v, and your Vin is 12v, then you can provide the power for the motor from Vin, and still control it from the Arduino - you would use a transistor to turn the +5v from one of the digital pins (set to output) to 12v from Vin. This is typically what happens on a "motor driver" - for example, see http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/image/data/tutorial/bipolar-stepper-drive.jpg - on the left-hand side, you will see "motor supply" - this runs at a higher voltage (and is isolated from +5v and Arduino pins), and if your motor needs what the barrel jack supplies (and is no more than 12v), then Vin is perfect.

The other situation is that you can put +7v to +12v INTO the Vin, instead of using the barrel jack - this will power your Arduino.

Comment: Thanks, also when do you think it would be acceptable to attach the positive or negative end of a power supply to an I/O pin?

Comment: Directly connected, there's no point, though it's not unusual to connect it via a resistor as a part of a voltage divider.